# Protoc installed by brew seems not to work in a custom build rule

Tags: xcode, homebrew, grpc, protoc

I've got a M1, with XCode 13.2.1 and monterey.

I've installed brew following the official steps and also I did the extra two steps so the new brew path is added to my path.

Additionally I've added `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` to my `.zshrc`

I've installed `protobuf` and `swift-protobuf` with brew and I can run both in the terminal with no errors.

But when I use `protoc` in a custom script in XCode build rules, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: protoc: command not found
/bin/sh: line 7: protoc: command not found
/bin/sh: line 9: protoc: command not found
```

I could add the path of `protoc` which I got from `which protoc` but I'm not sure if that would make a problem for other architectures.

Any idea why if `protoc` is running in my terminal, it's not running in custom script in XCode Build Rules?

Comment: Looks like you XCode script didn't find the protoc on path. Try to add `export ...` to `~/.bash_profile` or add to your script.

Comment: I end up exporting the `hombrew` path if it exists: 

`if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/bin" ];
then
    export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
fi`

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
/usr/local/bin
```

if there isn't the bin folder create it. Maybe it doesn't work from terminal, you can do it from Finder

After that go to the folder from the terminal and write

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc protoc
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc-gen-swift protoc-gen-swift
```

Quit Xcode, clean build folder and retry